# Laravel eloquent where makes array as object

Tags: php, laravel

The structure is that:

```
$data = table->select->join->get();
if(...) {
    $data = $data->where();
}
return $data
```

So the first line returns array of objects. After that there is condition, if it's true, it makes this array like object, like:

```
{5: {...}, 6: {...}}
```

I need if = true, then I need response `[{}, {}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use collection method [values()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-values) to make it without keys:

```php
if(...) {
    $data = $data->where()->values()->all();
}
```